# How to properly invoke Python 3 script from SPSS syntax window using SCRIPT command (+ additional problems during runtime)

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, spss

I would like to run two Python **3** scripts from SPSS syntax window. It is possible to perform it using `BEGIN PROGRAM-END PROGRAM.` block or `SCRIPT` command. This time I need to find a solution using second command.

Simplified code:

```
*** MACROS.
define export_tabs (!positional !tokens (1))

  output modify
  /select logs headings texts warnings pagetitles outlineheaders notes
  /deleteobject delete = yes.

  OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS EXPORT = visible  LAYERS = printsetting  MODELVIEWS = printsetting
  /XLSX  DOCUMENTFILE = "doc.xlsx"
  OPERATION = createsheet
  sheet = !quote(!unquote(!1))
  LOCATION = lastcolumn NOTESCAPTIONS = no

!enddefine.

define matrix_tab (!positional !charend('/')
  /!positional !charend('/')
  /!positional !charend('/')
  /!positional !charend('/')
  /stat = !tokens (1))

  !do !i !in (!3)

  ctables
  /mrsets countduplicates = no
  /vlabels variables = !concat(!1,_,!2,_,!i) display = label
  /table !concat(!1,_,!2,_,!i)
  [rowpct.responses.count !concat(!unquote(!stat),"40.0"), totals[count f40.0]]
  /slabels position = column visible = no
  /clabels rowlabels = opposite
  /categories variables = !concat(!1,_,!2,_,!i) order = a key = value
  empty = include total = yes label = "VALID COUNT" position = after
  /titles title = !upcase(!4).

  !doend

!enddefine.

*** REPORT.
* Sheet 1.
output close all.
matrix_tab $Q1 / 1 / 1 2 / "QUESTION 1" / stat="pct".

script "C:\path\script 1.py".
script "C:\path\script 2.py".

export_tabs "Q1".

* Sheet 2.
output close all.
matrix_tab $Q2 / 2 / 3 4 / "QUESTION 2" / stat="pct".

script "C:\path\script 1.py".
script "C:\path\script 2.py".

export_tabs "Q2".
```

When I run a block for the first sheet everything works fine. However, when I run a block for the second sheet SPSS doesn't execute Python scripts and jumps straight to `export_tabs` macro (problems with synchronization?). I thought a problem had been possibly in a way I executed `SCRIPT` command. So I tried this:

```
script "C:\path\script 1.py" pythonversion = 3.
script "C:\path\script 2.py" pythonversion = 3.
```

but in effect SPSS - even though the syntax window coloured these parts of syntax - returned this error message:

```
>Error # 3251 in column 152.  Text: pythonversion 
>The SCRIPT command contains unrecognized text following the the file 
>specification.  The optional parameter must be a quoted string enclosed in 
>parentheses. 
>Execution of this command stops.
```

Has anyone of you had such problem and/or have an idea why this happens?

**NOTE:** Both Python scripts run smoothly from the Python 3.4.3 shell installed with the version of SPSS I have, thus I don't think the core of the problem is within those codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a document defect in the way this keyword was implemented.  I have been able to replicate it and have logged a defect with IBM SPSS Statistics Development.

In this case, the order matters.  Rather than this:

```
script "C:\path\script 2.py" pythonversion = 3.
```

Try instead:

```
script pythonversion = 3 "C:\path\script 2.py".
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: There's another aspect of this problem. Please check here: [link](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=4003&MessageKey=39d702db-1a0b-4642-820a-82b13ee0bc8a&CommunityKey=886b6874-0fb1-402c-8243-c70ef8179a99&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2fcommunity%2fuser%2fdatascience%2fcommunities%2fcommunity-home%2fdigestviewer%3fcommunitykey%3d886b6874-0fb1-402c-8243-c70ef8179a99%26tab%3ddigestviewer). Back in 2020 I used version 25/26 of SPSS. Now I use 27.

Comment: This issue was resolved by interim fix in IBM SPSS Statistics 27.0.1.0.  The code change of that Interim Fix did not make it into Statistics 28.0.0.0, but was present in 28.0.1.1 and later.  See Known Issue [DT137879] https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/aCI3p00000009Wn)